# mysql data insert prob in a simple query

Tags: php, mysql

pretty simple code in php and mysql:

code inserting data in mysql table :

```
<?php

include("config.php");

$sql="INSERT INTO messages_sent (to) VALUES (35)";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
    echo("<br>Sorry the message could not be inserted into table messages_sent</br><br>");
    die(mysql_error());     
}else{      
    echo("<br>Message Inserted</br>");
}    

?>
```

table creation code follows:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages_sent`(
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`to` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`from` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`msg` TEXT NOT NULL,
`viewed` TINYINT(2)NOT NULL,
`time` DATETIME NOT NULL
)";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
    echo("Sorry the create query for table messages_sent could not be executed ");
    die(mysql_error());     
}
```

if i insert data in msg column, it is no prob but if the column is `to` or `from` then syntax error problem occurs.

Solution?

Comment: It's probably name clashing problem. Choose other names for `from` and `to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the schema of your table, you are setting `NOT NULL` with none `DEFAULT` value to other fields. so basically you cannot execute

`INSERT INTO messages_sent (to) VALUES (35)`

because you are leaving other fields `NULL` and ALSO `FROM` and `TO` are [Reserved Word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mySQL. Or instead use back ticks `` ` `` inside your query.

ex.

```
INSERT INTO `tableName` (`colName`) VALUES (valueHere)
```

Answer (score 0):

`from` is keyword use back ticks like this `from`

Comment: Or even do not use reserved words at all.

Comment: to avoid confusion and these syntax error , it is good not to use reserved words

Answer (score 0):

In your table schema of u are setting NOT NULL to all fields. your query is executed but in your table does not accept null values. so Error is occur. Please change NOT NULL to NULL or change query and ALSO FROM and TO are reserved words in MySQL